# attach style.less to wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, less

I have a question , how can I attach style.less to my wordpress theme  ?

I wrote this :

```
<script src="js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" media="all" href="less/style.less">
```

but i didn't any changes

thanks

Comment: does less.js compile the less file for you? Did you place this in the header.php file? Do the paths resolve? What have you done to debug this?

Comment: yeah i put this in header.php on head tag , when i use this everywhere except wordpress works but in theme directory wrodpress didn't any changes

Comment: are you positive you put it in the header.php file that's in the currently active theme's directory?

Answer (score 0):

First in your `functions.php`

```
require_once( 'wp-less/wp-less.php' );
```

Then try enqueue the `css` file

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'less-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.less' );
```

In your `functions.php` you can write your custom hooks

```
function nt_less() {



      if ( ! is_admin() ) {
              wp_enqueue_style( 'screen', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/screen.less', null, '2.2', 'screen' );
              wp_enqueue_style( 'print', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/print.less', null, '2.2', 'print' );
         }

    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nt_less');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the wordpress lessify plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/lessify-wp/ . Just install and activate it and it will do the trick.